# Why does Ham Radio Deluxe stops working when I change the AGC setting on my Icom IC-705 radio?

Tags: icom, equipment-troubleshooting, computer-control, ham-radio-deluxe, icom-ic-705

When I start rig control on Ham Radio Deluxe it works as long as AGC in my Icom IC-705 is in medium and I don't change it. If it's in slow it manages to read the frequency, but then it gets stuck. If it's in fast I think the same thing happen most of the time. If I change it while Ham Radio Deluxe is running the same thing happens.

I think this is much better illustrated with a video:

https://youtu.be/clYnycVZZPQ